# how to calculate height of horizontal cross bar from baseline(assume) of handwritten letter t using python (opencv)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have searched about it on the internet but didn't find anything related. If any related information or links or method you have then that would be appreciated .

And image contains only letter t which is handwritten and I want to find properties which are related to that letter and one of the property is the height of cross-bar from baseline.

Comment: try to abstract your problem. you will most likely not find a step by step  tutorial on how to calculate the cross bar height of a "t"...
any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: I have to find the height from baseline in pixels and i dont know any logic.

Comment: maybe you should start with the basics then... you can't read a book if you don't know any letters.

Comment: ohh actually i want the height because i am trying to detect personality traits.

Comment: You should start with some basic topics such as *Image Thresholding, Find contours, contour properties*. The first step would be to use some appropriate technique to segment the "t" from the input image, Then apply some contour properties to calculate the desired features.